# Spring Data Couchbase findById always returns null

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

Am i heading entirely down the wrong road? 
Should this work?

I'm trying to build a query that restricts the selection based on a boolean

e.g. `findByIdAndFieldIsTrue(id)`

This always returns no values. If I narrow this and just do `findById(id)` i still get no results which seems odd. I have tried a number of permutations of Id & field in the method name but none work.

```
Entity {
  @Id
  String id
  boolean field
}

interface EntityRepository BaseRepository, Repository {
  findByIdAndFieldIsTrue(id)
}
```

I tried without the `BaseRepository` thinking maybe the findOne method was interfering but no luck.

Update:

After adding the logger suggested in the answer I can get the query

```
{"statement":"SELECT META(`mybucket`).id AS _ID, META(`mybucket`).cas AS _CAS, `mybucket`.* FROM `mybucket` WHERE (`id` = \"entity::9627ff50-531d-4191-a9dc-07b48ba77fe9\") AND `_class` = \"com.myrepo.repository.api.Entity\"","scan_consistency":"statement_plus"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: N1QL forces you to use the USE KEY construct to select by id... That will be much much harder to integrate, looks like the workaround is the easiest path (see below)

I think this is an overlook of query derivation on the `@Id` field. In Couchbase, that field maps to the document's key and isn't contained in the document's body, so the N1QL query needs to take that into account.

Can you activate logging for the query generation? There's an `AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.class` logger that will log the generated N1QL in `DEBUG` mode. It will allow us to see what the query looks like and confirm that a special step must be taken for the @Id field...

I know it wouldn't be as performant if deserialization is complex, but a workaround could be to use `findOne` and then check the field.

Comment: I updated my answer with the query, I changed the meta details but I imagine that doesn't affect what your looking for here. As for using findOne and then filtering the results that's my current work around

Comment: Yep, it generates a where clause on "id"  rather than "_ID"... Maybe using an `@Field("_ID")` annotation would help in that corner case (although the id field is usually managed independently of other fields)

Comment: That does indeed result in the the where clause using `_ID` but still does not return a result. I tried in the couchbase admin console with this query with a known existing id `SELECT * FROM myBucket WHERE _ID = "product::0919893e-9411-4c41-8403-6753d7e1910f"` but no result

Comment: Should I open an issue for this? I couldn't find one on https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH

Comment: Yes, please file an enhancement issue, but keep in mind that won't necessarily be easy and straightforward to address...

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work with the following:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id IN $1")
List<Entity> findByIdIn(JsonArray ids);
```

To get the `JsonArray` from a list do the following:

```
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonArray;
.
.
.
repository.findByIdIn(JsonArray.from(myList));
```